# Can we think of the Riemann curvature tensor as a tensor-valued 2-form and integrate it over a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, curvature, holonomy

The usual physical interpretation of the Reimann tensor $R^\mu_{\ \ \nu \rho \sigma}$ at a given point $p$ on a manifold $M$ is that it inputs an infinitesimal vector $v^\nu$ and two other infinitesimal vectors $x^\rho$ and $x^\sigma$, the latter of which determine an infinitesimal parallelogram-shaped loop in $M$ anchored at $p$, and outputs the amount by which $v^\nu$ changes after being parallel-transported around the infinitesimal loop. That is, I believe it gives the [holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) of *infinitesimal* oriented loops with base point $p$ lying in the $x^\rho$-$x^\sigma$ plane.

There are other, equivalent ways to think about what type of mathematical object the Riemann curvature tensor is. E.g. one way to think of it as a self-adjoint operator on the real inner product space of two-forms. (This interpretation is arguably more natural for the "all-lowered" version $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$.)

Is it also possible to think of the Riemann tensor as a linear-operator-valued two-form in its last two indices $\rho$ and $\sigma$, and therefore integrate it over a 2D surface in the manifold? I've only ever seen the Riemann tensor described in terms of *infinitesimal* loops in the manifold. But is it legitimate to think of it as a two-form and integrate it (over $\rho$ and $\sigma$) over a *finite* surface $S$, and get the holonomy of the oriented boundary loop $\partial S$?

On the one hand, this seems plausible by the general heuristic picture for Green's theorem:
[image]

On the other hand, I doubt that it's correct, because (a) I can't find any sources saying that it is, and (b) more concretely, it seems to me that the holonomy of an oriented loop $\partial S$ should depend on the base point (although I'm not sure about that). But the formal integral
$$
\iint_S R^\mu_{\ \ \nu \rho \sigma} dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma
$$
does not pick out any distinguished point on $\partial S$.

Is there any sense in which this is a legitimate operation? If not, is there any other way to construct the (pseudo-)Riemannian holonomy of arbitrary oriented loops (with base point) in $M$ from the Riemann tensor? Or does that require knowing the connection and/or the full metric tensor?

I know very little about tensor-valued differential forms, so this might all be complete nonsense. I suspect the fact that the Riemann tensor is an actual tensor means that this *doesn't* work, because for tensor-valued forms the "form" indices and the "tensor" indices somehow transform differently under coordinate transformations.

**Edit:** Apparently the Riemann tensor can be thought of as a Lie-algebra-valued two-form (that takes values in $\mathfrak{so}(n)$) called the [curvature form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_form). I don't know how integration of Lie-algebra-valued differential forms works, though.

Comment: The Riemann curvature is indeed (naturally) thought of as an endomorphism-valued 2-form (for a vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$, the curvature of a connection on it is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued $2$-form on $M$). We can integrate vector space-valued forms, however, integrating vector-**bundle**-valued forms (which is what the Riemann curvature is) isn’t well defined because you can’t add elements in different fibers, unless you fix once and for all an isomorphism to a fixed fiber (and you only have an isomorphism here via parallel-transport once you fix a curve… but this is arbitrary).

Comment: in general, what you can do is pair vector-bundle valued forms with dual-bundle valued forms to obtain usual scalar forms, and you can integrate this scalar form over a surface in $M$. As you vary over “all” possible dual bundle forms, you can morally think of it as having picked out all the necessary components of the supposed integral of the curvature tensor. But I haven’t seen this (or any consequences of thinking along these lines) written up anywhere (not that I’ve looked hard for it or thought much about it).

Comment: Here is an explanation of how to integrate the curvature tensor on a surface to get the holonomy around a curve. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4583484/10584

Comment: Start with the case of a surface and integrate a scalar-valued 2-form. In the higher-dimensional case you’ll need to contract out those other indices by choosing appropriate vector fields (after lowering the upper index) along your surface.

Comment: @peek-a-boo For flat manifolds, there is a natural isomorphism between fibers because parallel transport is path-independent, correct? Can we always integrate any tensor field defined on a *flat* manifold over any submanifold? Or maybe can we only integrate a set of $m$ totally antisymmetric tensor indices over a submanifold of dimension $m$, to get a lower-rank tensor?

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you clarify what you mean by "start with"? I know that we can integrate regular (scalar-valued) two-forms over a surface, but how does that apply to my question?

Comment: @tparker on a flat connected $n$-manifold, once you fix a particular base point $x_0$, you can compute integrals of tensor-field-valued differential $n$-forms on $M$, because using parallel transport, this simply amounts to computing the integral of an $n$-form on $M$ with values in a single vector space $T_{x_0}M$ (so once you fix a basis for this vector space, it amounts to carrying out $n$ standard integrals of scalar $n$-forms on $M$). If you change the base point $x_0$ to $y_0$, the result will change of course (by the corresponding parallel-transport isomorphism $T_{x_0}M\to T_{y_0}M$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Why do you need to choose a base point to integrate over a submanifold?

Comment: a-priori, you have a tensor field. i.e a tensor at every point. But to integrate, you need to bring them all to the same vector space. But there are obviously many choices of such vector spaces. Once you fix the base point, you can consider a tensor-field as simply a function $f:M\to V$ (where $V=T^r_s(T_{x_0}M)$ for some fixed $x_0$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay. So if I have a tensor field on a flat manifold described in Cartesian coordinates, and I just do a naive componentwise integral over some submanifold to get a fixed tensor of the same rank as the tensor field, then you're saying that implicitly I'm really treating the tensor field as a tensor-valued differential form and integrating the differential form?